# How to change the colors of specific bars using Javafx BarChart?

Tags: java, css, javafx, bar-chart

This is something that I have been searching for for a while while working on a project. The best I had been able to find was how to change all of the bars or independently based on their specific value. Neither felt like a proper solutions. You might want to change individual bars and the amounts of each may change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found ended up being fairly simple, but I did not find very good documentation on it and wanted to post it for future use.

*NOTE:* All of these bars are in the same series. A similar fix could probably be applied to bar charts using multiple series, but that caused a spacing issue for me when each category only needed one bar.

The following code will create a bar chart that with 4 categories to track and adds them to the chart.

```
public class BarChartExample extends Application {

final static String project = "Project - 20%";
final static String quiz = "Quiz - 10%";
final static String midterm = "Midterm - 30%";
final static String finalexam = "Final - 40%";

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Change Bar Color Example");
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final BarChart<String,Number> barChart = new BarChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    xAxis.setLabel("Assignment Type");
    yAxis.setLabel("Percentage");

    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(project, 20));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(quiz, 10));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(midterm, 30));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(finalexam, 40));
    barChart.getData().add(series);
```

This next bit is the part relevant to this post. This is where the color change happens. The bars are considered Nodes, so you can set each bar equal to a node variable and use CSS to change it's style.

```
    Node n = barChart.lookup(".data0.chart-bar");
    n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: red");
    n = barChart.lookup(".data1.chart-bar");
    n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: blue");
    n = barChart.lookup(".data2.chart-bar");
    n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: green");
    n = barChart.lookup(".data3.chart-bar");
    n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: orange");
```

The rest is just getting rid of the legend (since in this case it's unnecessary) and filling out the remaining necessary code to make it run.

```
    barChart.setLegendVisible(false);
    VBox vbox = new VBox(barChart);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Application.launch(args);
}
```

}

I hope this helps anyone looking into trying to set bars with specific colors.

Comment: It's generally (much) better to do this using an external CSS file, than to use a `lookup`.

Comment: Can I ask why? I can see that making sense if you have a lot of formatting, but if you are just using a few lines of code, why would it be necessary to create a style sheet just for that?

Comment: Lookups are pretty volatile. For example, they won't work until CSS has been applied, which typically won't happen until the first layout pass, i.e. Until after the scene has been rendered once. So if you tried to do this in the initialize method of a controller, for example, there's a good chance it would fail with null pointer exceptions.